# Javascript is working locally on windows but not on the webserver

Tags: javascript, html

So i am trying to implement a menu (header.html) on all webpages on my website using a script from w3.

The Script works totally fine on my Windows PC when I run it from an USB stick.
However, if I try to launch the website from the USB-Stick on my Mac, it doesn't work anymore. When I upload the Webpage to the webserver, it doesnt work on Win or Mac. Is there any simple fix or do I need to install Node.js? (As far as I know, Javascript is Client-Sided and it should work on all browsers with Javascript enabled)

Sample HTML File:

```
  <title>Sample</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="favicon.ico" href="icon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <div id='website'>

    <div id='main'>

      <!-- Including the Header using a script -->
      <div w3-include-html="header.html"></div>
      <script src="w3-include-HTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <div id='contmain'>
        <span id='page_title'> Videos</span>      
        <div id='center_text'>   
          <b>Video 1</b>               
          <iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id='center_text'>      
          <b>Video 2</b>
          <iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>           
      </div>

      <div id='contmain'>
        <div id='center_text'>
          <b>Video 3</b>  <br>
          <iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="foulard"></div>
  <div class="logophoto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
(function () {

myHTMLInclude();

function myHTMLInclude() {
  var z, i, a, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    if (z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html")) {
      a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
      file = z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html");
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          a.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          a.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
          z[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, z[i]);
          myHTMLInclude();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
}

})();
```

Comment: "w3-include-HTML.js" - is the file name exactly that, with upper case "HTML"?

Comment: that fixed it!!! it wasnt upper case thanks a lot! i spent hours on it!

Comment: Checking your browsers developer tools network/console tabs would have shown you getting 404 errors, always check those when debugging

Comment: on which event you are call this function

Comment: call you script function and include your script in head section

Answer (score 1):

File systems on Windows do not differentiate between lower case and upper case file names, so in your case "w3-include-HTML.js" would be equal to "w3-include-html.js".

On most webservers (mostly Linux) and Mac OS system you have to take care about lower and upper case file names.

That explains why it is working on Windows, but not Mac OS or on your webserver